# how to loop list in a numpy.array with 3 arrays inside

Tags: python, arrays

I create a list with a loop

```
all_points=[]
    for i in range(3):
        list=[points[i].P[0], points[i].P[1], points[i].P[2]]
        all_points.append(list)
all_points = np.array(all_points)

#then I get 
[[0, 1, 2]
 [0, 1, 2]
 [0, 1, 2]]

#BUT I need 
[array([0, 0, 0], dtype=object), array(1, 1, 1], dtype=object), array([2, 2, 2], dtype=object)
```

tried to manually create a empty array but cant figure out how to build a three-array in one array data. and how to loop the data into the correct array.

Comment: requires more clarification... what is `points`? what is `P`?

Comment: It might help if you put `print(list)` inside the `for` loop (before the `append` line), and maybe `print(all_points)` before the `np.array` line.  That might make it clearer to you what your code is doing and how it is building up the result that is not quite right.

Comment: with points.[i] .P(0) i adress a secific x coordinate from a point in a list. P(1) y and P(2) z.

the (0, 1, 2,) stays for the given values from the list ... 

the loop runs anf fills the list correct. the problem is, that i need all 0 in one array and all 1 in another and all 2 in the last - like shown at the bottom ... and i do not know how to convert the list